# update magento issue

Tags: magento2, composer, credentials

I'm trying to update my Magento but has some issues with the composer.

When I try to use composer2 update, I get this:

```
composer update
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Authentication required (api.packages.vdc-services.io):
Username:
Password:

But it does not matter what username and password I use it says it's wrong credentials.

I'm starting to think it has something to do with my git repo. I tried to make a gir repo of my stage, but when I did pull a request it asked my for my username and password. but when I used my GitHub username and password it just said it was wrong.

Does anyone that knows what could be wrong?

Comment: which username and password you enter?

Comment: I first try the once in auth.json, but did not work. The git repo cred does not work, if it is not the cred for my github account then i have no idea what username and password it needs

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna you get the credentials from the auth.json and auth.json located in root folder and another way to get credentials from the Adobe account then go to my profile and click on access key and get the username and password as a public key and private key

Comment: I have looked at auth.json file and tried to use that, and that did not work.

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna It says the credentials you need are for `api.packages.vdc-services.io` (VMware Cloud Director API), not for the Magento repository. Perhaps you have something incorrect in the `composer.json` file. Do you mind sharing your composer.json file?

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna Please share your composer.json file here, and also provide details about the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username and password you need to use are authentication keys from the account that has the corresponding license to your Magento installation.

For Adobe Open Source installations, you can generate the keys yourself by following this article on devdocs - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/authentication-keys.html

For Adobe Commerce installations, you would have to do the same but with an account which has license to the corresponding installation type (on premise, commerce cloud etc).

The keys are also located in `auth.json` file in root of your installation but it could be outdated if you're not using commerce cloud as most of the other installations do not use it frequently. It should be something like below;

```
{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
         "password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Tu Van mentioned in the comments, it seems that the composer is not asking credentials for Magento but for VMware or maybe another VDC service, it maybe part of some custom deployment script. I think you should post your composer.lock file here as it maybe part of a module instead of being in the root composer.json.

You can get the authentication keys for it, if it is VMware by following this article - https://blogs.vmware.com/cloudprovider/2022/03/cloud-director-api-token.html

Answer (score 1):

As @tu-van mentioned in the comments, your problem is not the magento credentials but credentials for another repository.

Now it is possible that this is for a module you have added or for a dependency of them.

It might be a repository you should add from a purchase you made,
or it could be a mistake by composer. Composer goes through repositories in order then goes to the general composer public database to find packages. It will sometimes get it very wrong.

This is why people are asking for your composer.json so we can help guess which one.

Without this it is about general steps to figure it out, in as plain english as I can

**debugging issues in composer.json, what I have learned:**

Though you should be able to see which composer component it was dealing with if you look at the composer output while it happens (it will either tell you the name or at least you can eliminate all the successful ones) or the composer log?

The cause can be one of several options:

- you recently updated magento but some old dependency is still around and not updatable anymore. Might need to have several stabs at the update until you can have a full clean run.(see points 0 and 1 below)
- you bought a module from a provider and need to login to that company and find the password. Or you're only being asked for a password because you haven't configured your live and dev domains on their admin. Even free modules might need it. Check each of the modules you added that you didn't get on the marketplace. There would be instructions how to add their repository and authentication for it.
- if all your modules are from the marketplace, then the issue is either a dependency or that composer package source resolution is trying to fetch the file from the developer's private repository instead of a public ones. This can be because of an old dependency (magento is slowly shedding Zend and other older packages) or for a current dependency it is going the wrong place (and you need to check and fix exactly which repository and version you are getting.)

At this stage what needs to be figured out from your composer.json

0. What are        "preferred-install" and "minimum-stability" set to?
   For magento I recommend preferred-install as "dist" and "minimum-stability" as "stable" ("prefer-stable": true). This will composer from going for developer beta repositories which might be passworded. Then if you need some modules in beta form require it for these only. Note that repositories and modules already added will not be changed by these settings as they will follow what is in your composer.lock and you'll have to re-require them or edit that file (see point 3)
1. To figure out which it is, run your composer update with dependencies (try -w and then -W) and with verbose, you ideally you can see where it hangs. If you are lucky you can remove the module it hangs on (or add it to ignore), update, then re-require it with a specific version, you might have fixed your issue.
2. Repository order and exclusion. You can control where composer takes modules from with the order of the repositories in the composer.json file. If it is taking a module or dependency from the wrong repository (because some developers have local copies) you could get odd errors like the one you have (those local copies are for developers only). If you can figure out where this is going wrong you can just add an exclude to that repository configuration.

For example I had to put magetrend ahead of magento as I wanted to have their version of the their modules, but then I had to add an exclude as they have a developer local copy of magento and I want the official repository.

```
    "magetrend": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magetrend.com",
        "exclude": [
            "magento/*"
        ]
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/",
        "canonical": false
    },
```

3. Once you know which module you can figure out if you have added the wrong stability or it is trying to get the live git repo instead of distribution package etc. then you will have to re-require the same package but the appropriate full command line options with --prefer-source --prefer-dist --prefer-stable in order to fix it.

If you can share parts of your composer.json we can help more precisely.